# Removing a segment of a frame

Tags: graphics, pstricks

I have the following MWE in PSTricks, showing a rectangle:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](5,5)
    \psframe(4,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

What I would like to is to remove the part of the right side spanned by the coordinates (4,1) and (4,3). What is the easiest way to achieve this? I could of course just superimpose a white line, but that seems like a wrong way to do it.

Comment: @PGFTricks: You are wrong! `pst-node` has _nothing_ to do with coordinate types, except nodes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a "correct" way is to draw a polyline:

```
\psline(4,1)(4,0)(0,0)(0,4)(4,4)(4,3)
```

and if you want to fill the area use:

```
\psframe*[linecolor=cyan!40](4,4)
\psline(4,1)(4,0)(0,0)(0,4)(4,4)(4,3)
```

Comment: is there a way to remove the horizontal lines at points (4, 1) and (4,3)?

Comment: sorry, I do not understand what lines do you mean. At  (4, 1) and (4,3) are no horizontal lines

Answer (score 2):

Just another answer with PSTricks. But the boundary of the filled region passes the middle of the line, you can see it easily by changing `linewidth=5\pslinewidth`, for example.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,4)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray]
    {
        \psline(4,3)(4,4)(0,4)(0,0)(4,0)(4,1)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Apparently the code above is equivalent to the following (based on Herbert's surprising comment below).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,4)
    \psline[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray](4,3)(4,4)(0,4)(0,0)(4,0)(4,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Or with an overkill solution below.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,4)
\pscustom
{
    \psline(4,3)(4,4)(0,4)(0,0)(4,0)(4,1)
    \gsave
        \closepath
        \fill[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray]
    \grestore
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\psline[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray](4,3)...`  does the same without `\pscustom`.